Increase the size of a label of a phantom arrow in a tikz-cd diagram
Consider the following diagram:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsfonts}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3em, column sep=3em]
        A \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & B \arrow[d] \\
        C \arrow[r] & \arrow[lu, phantom, "\ulcorner", pos=0] D
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}

I would like to increase the size of the symbol \ulcorner a little bit. There are similar questions already asked. I tried
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsfonts}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3em, column sep=3em]
        A \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & B \arrow[d] \\
        C \arrow[r] & \arrow[lu, phantom, "{\Large\ulcorner}", pos=0] D
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}

It does not work. What is the trick ?

You can change the size like this:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsfonts}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3em, column sep=3em]
        A \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & B \arrow[d] \\
        C \arrow[r] & \arrow[lu, phantom,"{\ulcorner}"{font=\Huge}, pos=0] D
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}


